# zipping binary data in java

Tags: java, servlets, io, zip

I am trying to zip a group of binary data (result set returned from database) into a single file. Which can be downloaded via web application. Following code is used to zip the result set and write the zip file to [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html)

```
String outFilename = "outfile.zip";
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= " + outFilename);
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(os);
for (int i = 0; i < cardFileList.size(); i++) {

    CardFile cardFile = cardFileList.get(i);
    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(cardFile.getBinaryFileName()));
    out.write(cardFile.getBinaryFile(), 0, cardFile.getBinaryFile().length);
    out.closeEntry();
}
// Complete the ZIP file
out.flush();
out.close();
os.close();
```

The problem is that while unzipping the downloaded zip file using WinRar I get following error :

> File Path: Either multipart or corrupt ZIP archive

Can someone point out where am I making mistake?. Any help would be appreciated.

[EDIT] I tried `response.setContentType("application/zip");` but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("out.zip");
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(os);
try
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        ZipEntry curEntry = new ZipEntry("file" + i + ".txt");
        zos.putNextEntry(curEntry);
        zos.write(("Good morning " + i).getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
}
finally
{
    zos.close();
}
```

Zip files generated with this code opens up with 7-zip without problem.

- Check that the response from the servlet is not actually a 404 or 500 error page.  Pick a small response and open it up with a hex editor or even a text editor.  Zip files start with a 'PK' magic number which should be visible even in a text editor.
- Try saving to file instead of servlet output stream for starters and see if that makes a difference.
- Could there be a filter modifying your servlet's output / corrupting the ZIP?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct for producing the file.  So the problem is probably in your downloading.

1. look at the file you have downloaded.  What is it's size?
2. try a tool other than your WinRar and see what you have.  7Zip is decent.