# How to create a zip file from binary data without knowing contents of zip file in java?

Tags: java, zip, deserialization, file-handling, zipoutputstream

I am listening to binary data from queues which is actually a zip file data. I want to reconstruct the zip file using java code but I do not have any information about contents of zip file such as no of files, names of files and size of each file in zip file. I think this information is required when we create a zip file using ZipOutputStream and ZipEntry in java. Also, it is certain that zip file contain more than one file. Is there any way to construct zip file from this binary feed of data without knowing details about its content?

I have tried putting ZipEntry for only one file in ZipOutputStream but that only gives me garbage file and zip creation and successive uzipping does not work.

```
byte[] data = {}; // data received over mq
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("ZipFile.zip"))); // zip file to be created
ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry("Output.txt");  
// Creating zipentry for one file in zip 
ze.setSize(data.length);
zos.putNextEntry(ze);  
zos.write(data); // writing da
ta to zip output stream
zos.closeEntry();
zos.close();
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. If it's  "actually a zip file data", then why do you need to "reconstruct" it, as opposed to saving it as a file then later *reading* it?

Comment: If I just save it in a file and try to treat as a zip file, I am getting zip corrupted error msg.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create real file output.txt (with real size, real name, with your binary data) than add it to zip.
I guess, you only write it is a file. You are not putting a file, but the binary data, aren't you? (zip thinks that part of your data is meta information of txt file).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have taken the output.txt as only an example. I actually dont know how many files might be there in this zip file. So I cannot write all data to single text file. I have tried writing it to file and then unzipping it directly but it does not work.

Comment: You can separate your data in different files, it doesn't matter. Than you will read it one by one.

Comment: see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426441/zipping-binary-data-in-java